# Error when deleting SHAPES

Tags: excel, vba

A piece of my code (to delete all shapes in the sheet) suddenly started to throw an error

> "Object does not support this property or method"

and highlights the row `If Shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then` This is a part of a big code I continuously update, but the code below is not a part of any cycle, IF, etc. What could be a reason?

```
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ActWS.Shapes                                                        
    If Shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then Shp.Delete
Next Shp
```

Comment: is this code inside of Excel itself or is it run inside of another office application?

Comment: Has `ActWS` been **Set** somewhere ??

Comment: @ScottHoltzman it is a part of excel file itself, as a sheet's private sub `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` (sheet is called ActWS, so the action suppose to happen inside this sheet when I activate it)

Comment: Is sheet **object** (inside the VBE) called `ActWs` or is the sheet **name** `ActWs`. If it's the name, or really regardless, using `Me.Shapes` will work either way. Me works because it is inside a worksheet level module.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman unfortunately it gives the same error. Seems like I will have to get back to the older version of the file, that worked well

Comment: this code should work, so take heed to what changes you made between files and resolve what is different that is causing the error.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, that's what I've started doing. But in general, my understanding of VBA tells me that specifically this error should not appear in the first place. Maybe some other one, but this... The code worked before. And even if it did not, the Shape type of variant do support this property... I am lost in the logic of VBA =)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works by me. Probably there is something with the shapes, that you are using. Can you run this:

```
Public Sub ale()

Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
        Debug.Print Shp.Name
        Shp.Delete
    End If
Next Shp

End Sub
```

And share what is the last result from the Immediate window before the error comes? Also, can you confirm on which line of the new code the error comes?

Comment: The code works. And my code worked before. However after my last update it does not

Comment: I do not get it. If you exchange my code with yours, does it work? If yes -> then probably the error was that you have not set correctly ActWS. If no -> can you run it with my code and tell me what is the name of the last shape?

Comment: Sheets are named correcty. Ok, I just noticed that my code crashes only in one case - when i switch from one specific sheet to ActWS. That sheet has private sub on deactivation, and ActWS has this piece of code that gives error in private sub on activation. By the way, your code gives `Shape.Name = <object required>`